# How to open and catch all the links inside an accordion?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I have a website with some accordion elements like this:

[image]

```
    <div class="col-md-12">

        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" title="Click to expand pet name" href="#petName1">
            <span class="list-unstyled" style="text-decoration: none;"></span> Dog
         </a>


        <ul id="petName1" class="collapse">

                <li>
                    <a href="/scripts/cder/daf/index.cfm?event=overview.process&ApplNo=200465" title="Click to view Dog | PET SHOP">
                              Dog</a> | PET SHOP
                    </a>

                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="/scripts/cder/daf/index.cfm?event=overview.process&ApplNo=203874" title="Click to view Dog | PET SHOP">
                              Dog</a> | PET SHOP
                    </a>

                </li>

        </ul>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>

    <div class="col-md-12">

        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" title="Click to expand pet name" href="#petName2">
            <span class="list-unstyled" style="text-decoration: none;"></span> Cat
         </a>


        <ul id="petName2" class="collapse">

                <li>
                    <a href="/scripts/cder/daf/index.cfm?event=overview.process&ApplNo=076477" title="Click to view Cat">
                              Cat
                    </a>

                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="/scripts/cder/daf/index.cfm?event=overview.process&ApplNo=077575" title="Click to view Cat">
                              Cat
                    </a>

                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="/scripts/cder/daf/index.cfm?event=overview.process&ApplNo=078773" title="Click to view Cat">
                              Cat</a>
                    </a>

                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="/scripts/cder/daf/index.cfm?event=overview.process&ApplNo=090548" title="Click to view Cat">
                              Cat</a> 
                    </a>

                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="/scripts/cder/daf/index.cfm?event=overview.process&ApplNo=091226" title="Click to view Cat">
                              Cat</a> 
                    </a>

                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="/scripts/cder/daf/index.cfm?event=overview.process&ApplNo=091624" title="Click to view Cat">
                              Cat</a>
                    </a>

                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="/scripts/cder/daf/index.cfm?event=overview.process&ApplNo=091650" title="Click to view Cat">
                              Cat</a>
                    </a>

                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="/scripts/cder/daf/index.cfm?event=overview.process&ApplNo=202357" title="Click to view Cat">
                              Cat</a> 
                    </a>

                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="/scripts/cder/daf/index.cfm?event=overview.process&ApplNo=204846" title="Click to view Cat">
                              Cat</a>
                    </a>

                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="/scripts/cder/daf/index.cfm?event=overview.process&ApplNo=205300" title="Click to view Cat">
                              Cat</a>
                    </a>

                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="/scripts/cder/daf/index.cfm?event=overview.process&ApplNo=205519" title="Click to view Cat">
                              Cat</a>
                    </a>

                </li>

        </ul>


        </div>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>

    <div class="col-md-12">

        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" title="Click to expand pet name" href="#petName3">
            <span class="list-unstyled" style="text-decoration: none;"></span> Gold Fish 
         </a>

        <ul id="petName3" class="collapse">

                <li>
                    <a href="/scripts/cder/daf/index.cfm?event=overview.process&ApplNo=021540" title="Click to view Gold Fish">
                              Gold Fish </a>
                    </a>

                </li>

        </ul>


        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>

    <div class="col-md-12">

        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" title="Click to expand pet name" href="#petName4">
            <span class="list-unstyled" style="text-decoration: none;"></span> Horse 
         </a>


        <ul id="petName4" class="collapse">

                <li>
                    <a href="/scripts/cder/daf/index.cfm?event=overview.process&ApplNo=020702" title="Click to view Horse">
                              Horse </a>
                    </a>

                </li>

        </ul>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>

    <div class="col-md-12">

        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" title="Click to expand pet name" href="#petName5">
            <span class="list-unstyled" style="text-decoration: none;"></span> Ferret 
         </a>
        <ul id="petName5" class="collapse">

                <li>
                    <a href="/scripts/cder/daf/index.cfm?event=overview.process&ApplNo=200153" title="Click to view Ferret">
                              Ferret </a>
                    </a>
                </li>            
        </ul>

        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

How can I click with selenium web driver in all the sections and save the links below each section of the accordions?. I tried to:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://example.com")
inputElement = driver.find_element_by_id("searchterm")
inputElement.send_keys('pets')
inputElement.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
driver.find_element_by_id("mp-pusher").click()
inputElement.submit()
```

However, it doesn't worked since it doesn't do anything (it just stuck out). Any idea of how to get all the links and open all the accordions?.

Comment: Sometimes I just grab the source using the `driver.page_source` attribute (the browser source after all javascript run) and parse using something like beautifulsoup.

Comment: could you provide an example for this case?... thanks for the help! @PauloScardine

Answer (score 0):

following is the java code not sure about python but you can try the same logic

```
List<WebElement> accordions = driver.findElements(By.xpath("\\a[@data-parent='#accordion1']");
```

This will get all the accordion in list. Now iterate through list and click on each accordion.

To save link under each accordion you can use webelement of previous list.

Comment: I got this: `InvalidSelectorException: Message: Given xpath expression "\a[@data-parent='#accordion']" is invalid: SyntaxError: The expression is not a legal expression.`

Comment: its "\\a[@data-parent='#accordion1']"  you have written "\a[@data-parent='#accordion']"